# how to ignore errors in SaveChange EF4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, savechanges

Please see to example1. If some of the data will be entered incorrectly, EF4 will not survive nor any record.

The question: whether as a force to ignore an error in one record and continue on.

**example1:**

```
foreach (var tag in split)
{
    context.NameToResourcer.AddObject(new NameToResourcer()
    {
        id_resource = resource.id,
        name = tag
    });
}
context.NameToResourcer.AddObject(new NameToResourcer()
{
    id_resource = resource.id,
    name = ExtractDomainNameFromURL(resource.url)
});
try
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (UpdateException ex)
{

}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    throw;
}
```

example2 alternative:

```
foreach (var tag in split)
{
    try
    {
        context.NameToResourcer.AddObject(new NameToResourcer()
        {
            id_resource = resource.id,
            name = tag
        });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (UpdateException ex)
    {

    }
} 
try
{
    context.NameToResourcer.AddObject(new NameToResourcer()
    {
        id_resource = resource.id,
        name = ExtractDomainNameFromURL(resource.url)
    });
    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (UpdateException ex)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Context behaves like unit of work. It means that when you modify data and store them with the single call to `SaveChanges` you are telling EF that you want atomic operation - either all changes are successfully saved or all changes are rolled back. EF use a transaction internally to support this behavior. If you don't want this behavior you cannot save all data with single call to `SaveChanges`. You must use separate call for each atomic set of data.

Comment: You are able to do that by using multiple SaveChanges. I'm not aware of better solution.

Comment: How can you use a separate call for each atomic set of data?

Comment: @BadaBoom: You perform just modifications for one atomic set and call SaveChanges. Then you can perform another atomic set of changes and call SaveChanges again.

Comment: Not true, I will ask a question for that. I'm getting a DbUpdateException when doing that. But I'm not sure what you mean by 'atomic'?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to disable validation on saving.But I don't recommend it.

```
db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```